# Rails: Help with designing a model, and associating it correctly with others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a rails app which currently has 3 models: `Post`, `User` and `Movie`. I've listed the important fields in the models below

`Post: id: integer, user_id: integer, location_id: integer, description: string`

`Movie: id: integer, name: string, rating: decimal,  ...`

`User: id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string ...`

Now I want Users to be able to create Posts about a Movie, and my site will display these Posts. If there is a pre-existing Post about a Movie, then the `rating` that the User assigns to the Movie should be added and averaged with the pre-existing rating, and the `description` that the User assigns should be added to the list of descriptions already present in the Movie.

First question: How do I store a list of descriptions persistently as part of my `Movie` model? For example, is it possible to store an array of strings as part of the `Movie` model, or should I create a new `Description` model just for this purpose?

And after this, how do I associate these models so they behave as expected? My thoughts were:

`Post -> belongs_to -> User`, `User -> has_many -> Posts`, `Post -> has_one -> Movie` but I'm not sure this is the right way to associate them, and I do not have any experience with `:through` associations (which might be required here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct associations would be:

```
User has_many Post
Movie has_many Post
Post belongs_to User
Post belongs_to Movie
```

You'll need to add a movie_id column to posts table. Descriptions should stay in the Post model, not in the Movie model. When you want to show the posts on a particular movie, @movie.posts should get you there.

Comment: Plus, for maintaining average ratings, you'll need to maintain a rating_count to keep track of how many users have rated that movie. Start with rating = 0 and rating_count = 0. When a user rates a movie, new rating = (old rating + new rating) / (rating_count + 1). And increment the rating_count by 1.